# Как занести в Map данные из Excel файла? В java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[image: Это скрин из файла]

Добрый день!

Прошу подсказать как через Apache POI библиотеку  выгрузить данные из Excel так, чтобы их можно было поместить в мапу.  Например в файле есть колонка firstname и колонка interaction, нужно их поместить в мапу так, чтобы каждому имени соответствовала сумма всех его интеракций, т.е. ключом мапы должна быть firstname , а значением  сумма соответствующих ему интеракций.  Т.е. например для Denis сумма будет равна 7.

Comment: Если у вас есть код, который берёт последнее значение, не суммируя - стоит добавить его в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven POM:

```
 <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Java Code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        Map<String, Integer> interactions = new HashMap<>();

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.xlsx"));

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        sheet.forEach(row -> {
            String name = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));

            Integer interaction = Integer.parseInt(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(1)));

            if(!interactions.containsKey(name)) {
                interactions.put(name, 0);
            }
            interactions.put(name, interactions.get(name)+interaction);
        });

        workbook.close();

        System.out.println(interactions);

    }
}
```

Output: `{Mihail=9, Petr=10, Grigory=8, Denis=7}`

Answer (score -1):

Чисто алгоритмически задача решается так:
- Открываем книгу на чтение
- Берем первый лист
- Берем итератор по строкам, идем по нему
- В каждой строке берем итератор по ячейкам, идем по нему, читаем первую ячейку, проверяем есть ли в мапе по этому ключу значение. Если есть, прибавляем к нему значение второй ячейки, иначе кладем в мапу значение второй ячейки, по ключу = значению первой ячейки, переходим к следущей строке
- Идем пока не закончатся строки
- ??????
- PROFIT!!!1